# Pass by Value and Pass by reference in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to pass-by-reference in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157799/when-to-pass-by-reference-in-php)
>   [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

In PHP by default we have pass by value.I am wondering what would be good situations for passing values by reference.

Comment: i think this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "return" more than one variable it's helpful.  Functions like preg_match use it.

Answer (score -1):

Populating a Combobox, for example.

Doing something with a control, or an object in the main scope, but from another layer.

Fetching data from your data layer, and populating a ComboBox, by reference, instead of retrieving a list of values in the main scope (page) and populating the ComboBox there.