# Make bold specific part of string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like

```
 $array[]="This is a test";
 $array[]="This is a TEST";
 $array[]="TeSt this";
```

I need to make the string 'test' as `bold` like

```
 $array[]="This is a <b>test</b>";
 $array[]="This is a <b>TEST</b>";
 $array[]="<b>TeSt</b> this";
```

I have tried with `str_replace()` but it is case sensitive,

**Note:**
I need to make the given string bold and keep as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array_walk` PHP function to replace the string value within an array. Check below code

```
function my_str_replace(&$item){
  $item = preg_replace("/test/i", '<b>$0</b>', $item);
}

$array[]="This is a test";
$array[]="This is a TEST";
$array[]="TeSt this";

array_walk($array, 'my_str_replace');
```

**EDIT:** Based on John WH Smith's comment

You can simply use `$array = preg_replace("/test/i", '<b>$0</b>', $array);` which would do the magic

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend further reading about PHP references (`&$item`) here. Why not start there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157799/when-to-pass-by-reference-in-php (I am not sure `array_walk` is actually necessary here, as `preg_replace` can work with both strings and arrays (`mixed` parameter : http://fr2.php.net/preg_replace))

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for patterns instead of fixed strings like "test", have a look at REGEXes and `preg_replace` :

```
$str = preg_replace("#(test|otherword)#i", "<b>$1</b>", $str);
```

More about REGEXes :

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- http://uk.php.net/preg_replace

*Edit :* added "i" after the REGEX to remove case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like the one I wrote below:

```
function wrap_text_with_tags( $haystack, $needle , $beginning_tag, $end_tag ) {
    $needle_start = stripos($haystack, $needle);
    $needle_end = $needle_start + strlen($needle);
    $return_string = substr($haystack, 0, $needle_start) . $beginning_tag . $needle . $end_tag . substr($haystack, $needle_end);
    return $return_string;
}
```

So you'd be able to call it as follows:

```
$original_string = 'Writing PHP code can be fun!';
$return_string = wrap_text_with_tags( $original_string , 'PHP' , "<strong>" ,"</strong>");
```

When returned the strings will look as follows:

**Original String**

> Writing PHP code can be fun!

**Modified Result**

> Writing **PHP** code can be fun!

This function only works on the FIRST instance of a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It also keeps all uppercase letters uppercase and all lowercase letters lowercase.

```
    function wrapTextWithTags( $haystack, $needle , $tag ): string
    {
        $lowerHaystack = strtolower($haystack);
        $lowerNeedle = strtolower($needle);

        $start = stripos($lowerHaystack, $lowerNeedle);
        $length = strlen($needle);

        $textPart = substr($haystack, $start, $length);
        $boldPart = "<" . $tag . ">" . $textPart . "</" . $tag . ">";

        return str_replace($textPart, $boldPart, $haystack);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find using a `preg_replace()` call to be the most appropriate tool for this task because:

- it can affect all elements in the array without writing a loop,
- it can replace more than one substring within a string,
- adding a case-insensitive flag (`i`) is an easy and intuitive adjustment,
- adding word boundaries (`/b`) on either side of the "needle" word will ensure that only whole words are replaced
- when replacing the fullstring match, no parentheses / capture groups are necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/62qRT))

```
$array = [
    "This is a test",
    "This is a TEST",
    "Test this testy contest protest test!",
    "TeSt this",
];

var_export(
    preg_replace('/\btest\b/i', '<b>$0</b>', $array)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'This is a <b>test</b>',
  1 => 'This is a <b>TEST</b>',
  2 => '<b>Test</b> this testy contest protest <b>test</b>!',
  3 => '<b>TeSt</b> this',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [str_ireplace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). Case insensitive version of `str_replace`

Comment: `str_ireplace("test", "<b>test</b>", $string)` does make "test" bold, you can store this value somewhere else and keep your original text as is. This is a valid answer, will not be deleted no matter how many downvotes it gets.

Comment: After your edit, it is now clear (not so clear) that you want to replace `TeSt` with `<b>TeSt</b>`. You should use regex solution proposed

Comment: Sorry for implying that. In fact I later realized that I deserved a downvote. I should have understood that while replacing the text we should keep it as is, it was clear from your examples. Sorry again

Answer (score -1):

Try this
[Using str_ireplace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

```
str_ireplace("test", "<b>test</b>", $array);
str_ireplace("TSET", "<b>TEST</b>", $array);
```

Comment: @shijin Before post a question mention your exact requirement You said that ** I have tried with str_replace() but it is case sensitive,Please help me ** That is why I am proffered `str_ireplace`