# User defined PHP function fails to return updated variable

Tags: php, return-value, user-defined-functions

I am having some difficulty finding anything quite similar to what I am trying to accomplish with my code.  I have a while loop that executes for each instance of a variable located in a mysql database.

```
$lref = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM builtl");

while($lrow = mysqli_fetch_array($lref))
{
   //variables from builtl
   $partnum = $lrow['m3num'];
   $lqty = $lrow['qty'];
   //POST to DB
   postcode($partnum,$lqty);
   echo $lqty;
...//More code exists that is not part of the question
```

The user defined function postcode() only executes when the form submission button (excluded in sample code) is set.  Below is part of the function itself.

```
function postcode($partnum,$lqty)
{
    $bchk = $partnum."sb";
    if(isset($_POST[$bchk]))
    {
    //builtl
    $lqty=$lqty-1;
    $bltmod="UPDATE builtl SET qty=$lqty WHERE m3num=$partnum";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$bltmod))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    }
}
```

When the code executes, the database is updated inside of the function like it should, but the while loop has already been generated and doesn't pull the new value of $lqty in.  I want some of my later code inside the while loop to use the updated value of $lqty.  Would using return somewhere help me with this or would reloading the page to pull the new DB value be easier?

Comment: Are you expecting `postcode()` to update the value of `$lqty`?  You need to either have it `return $lqty;`, or make `$lqty` a reference (`function postcode($partnum, &$lqty)`).  If you make it a reference, then when it's updated in the function, it'll be updated outside.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

`function postcode($partnum,$lqty)`

to

`function postcode($partnum,&$lqty)`

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: You should avoid passing by reference when possible. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157799/when-to-pass-by-reference-in-php

Comment: Sure, but this seems like a reasonable case. "I want some of my later code inside the while loop to use the updated value of $lqty" was what made me think it appropriate. Making the postcode function return a value (which is reasonable) is as likely to cause side-effects if it is ever called by other code. But point taken.

Comment: Passing by reference seems to be the ideal solution for my situation.  This solution worked, thank you Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to call postcode():

```
$lqty = postcode($partnum,$lqty);
```

and return `$lqty` from `postcode()` at the end of the function:

```
return $lqty;
```

Comment: I left out that I am using my submission button to reload the entire page.  Even with this code added, the value is not returned from the function.

Comment: If you are reloading the entire page, `$_POST` won't be set anymore, so `$lqty` isn't getting updated.

Comment: On the first instance of the reload, assuming the submit caused the reload, the  $_POST is set and the code executes properly.  I read somewhere that PHP functions have trouble returning values when isset is used, is that possibly what I am facing here?

Comment: I've never heard of or run into that problem. I can't imagine any scenario where this wouldn't work. Are you sure you are returning the value from `postcode()` and catching it in the calling code?